# Laravel - How to add a JOIN and CASE-WHEN using Query Builder or Eloquent?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have the following working, raw SQL statement that I'm finding incredibly tough to convert into PHP, using Laravel/Query Builder/Eloquent.

```sql
SELECT aa.filepath, 
       aa.filename, 
       inst.instrument, 
       rl.raga, 
       ks.keysig, 
       aa.id    AS AAID, 
       likes.id AS LikesID 
FROM   (audioassets aa) 
       INNER JOIN instruments inst 
               ON aa.instrument_id = inst.id 
       INNER JOIN keysigs ks 
               ON aa.keysig_id = ks.id 
       LEFT JOIN ragalist rl 
              ON aa.raga_id = rl.i 
       LEFT JOIN likes 
              ON aa.id = likes.audioassets_id 
                 AND CASE likes.user_id 
                       WHEN 1 THEN true 
                       ELSE false 
                     END 
WHERE  ks.keysig LIKE '%' 
       AND inst.instrument LIKE '%';
```

**My Notes:**

- the issue I'm encountering is with trying to get the CASE-WHEN code to work in Laravel
- the "1" after "WHEN" is meant to be a variable, so it's just for testing right now
- all I'm trying to do is display a list of files on a "dashboard" AND show which files the currently logged in user has "liked" (no one else's likes)

**Here is my Laravel Eloquent code:**

```
$query = \App\Audioassets::where('instruments.instrument', 'LIKE', "%$ddinstselected%")
        ->where('keysigs.keysig', 'LIKE', "%$ddkeyselected%")
        ->join('instruments', 'audioassets.instrument_id', '=', 'instruments.id')
        ->leftjoin('ragalist', 'audioassets.raga_id', '=', 'ragalist.id')
        ->join('keysigs', 'audioassets.keysig_id', '=', 'keysigs.id')
        ->leftjoin('likes', 'likes.audioassets_id', '=', 'audioassets.id')
        ->where('likes.user_id', '=', $authuserid)
        ->select('audioassets.filepath', 'audioassets.filename', 
'instruments.instrument', 'ragalist.raga', 'keysigs.keysig', 'audioassets.id', 'likes.id as likesid');
```

This works fine in Laravel but does not incorporate the CASE-WHEN SQL, so all the "likes" are shown for all the users.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: DB::raw() might help you, use like select(DB::raw("count(*)"))

Comment: you can use whereRaw(), you can write SQL in this statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with below query

```
myFriendsData = DB::table('audioassets as aa')
    ->where('ks.keysig', 'LIKE', '%')
    ->join('instruments', 'audioassets.instrument_id', '=', 'instruments.id')
    ->leftjoin('ragalist', 'audioassets.raga_id', '=', 'ragalist.id')
    ->join('keysigs', 'audioassets.keysig_id', '=', 'keysigs.id')
    ->join('likes ',audioassets.id = likes.audioassets_id, function() {})
    ->whereRaw(
        '( 
            CASE 
                 WHEN likes.user_id = 1 THEN true ELSE false     
            END
        )'
    )
    ->select('audioassets.filepath', 'audioassets.filename','instruments.instrument', 'ragalist.raga', 'keysigs.keysig', 'audioassets.id', 'likes.id as likesid');
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [advance join clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#joins) and [`DB::raw()`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#raw-expressions):

```
<?php
$query = \App\Audioassets::where('instruments.instrument', 'LIKE', "%$ddinstselected%")
    ->where('keysigs.keysig', 'LIKE', "%$ddkeyselected%")
    ->join('instruments', 'audioassets.instrument_id', '=', 'instruments.id')
    ->leftjoin('ragalist', 'audioassets.raga_id', '=', 'ragalist.id')
    ->join('keysigs', 'audioassets.keysig_id', '=', 'keysigs.id')
    // Use join clause.
    ->leftJoin('likes', function ($join) {
        $join->on('aa.id', '=', 'likes.audioassets_id')
             // CASE WHEN by DB::raw()
             ->on(DB::raw('CASE likes.user_id WHEN 1 THEN true ELSE false'));
    )
    ->where('likes.user_id', '=', $authuserid)
    ->select(
        'audioassets.filepath',
        'audioassets.filename', 
        'instruments.instrument',
        'ragalist.raga',
        'keysigs.keysig',
        'audioassets.id',
        'likes.id as likesid'
    );
```

Join Clause API Reference: [Illuminate\Database\Query\JoinClause | Laravel API](https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Database/Query/JoinClause.html#method_on)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help!
I didn't get back around to responding to all the great helpers in this thread, but the answer was a mix of the two answers provided above. Here's the final code that works flawlessly:

```
$query = \App\Audioassets::where('instruments.instrument', 'LIKE', "%$ddinstselected%")
->where('keysigs.keysig', 'LIKE', "%$ddkeyselected%")
->leftJoin('likes', function ($join) use ($authuserid) {
    $join->on('audioassets.id', '=', 'likes.audioassets_id');
    $join->whereRaw(
        '(
                CASE
                    WHEN likes.user_id=? THEN true ELSE false
                END
        )'
        , [$authuserid]);
    })
->join('instruments', 'audioassets.instrument_id', '=', 'instruments.id')
->leftjoin('ragalist', 'audioassets.raga_id', '=', 'ragalist.id')
->join('keysigs', 'audioassets.keysig_id', '=', 'keysigs.id')
->select('audioassets.filepath', 'audioassets.filename', 'instruments.instrument', 'ragalist.raga', 'keysigs.keysig', 'audioassets.id', 'likes.id as likesid');
```